# How to make my JTextArea or JTextPane automatically create a new line?

Tags: java, jtextfield, jtextarea, jtextpane

In my program, I want a large area for typing in. I have been playing around with JTextPanes and JTextAreas. However if I continuously type, when I reach the end of the area, it does not automatically create a new line it just continues off the box, I know that I can add a horizontal scroll bar, but I would prefer it to just drop to a new line when I reach the end of the box. I saw something called dropMode and tried playing with this to see if it helped, but it just resulted in the following error "Unsupported drop mode for text". My program is GUI based, therefore the user will be typing directly into the area, not appending it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textArea.setLineWrap(true)` should work as you want.

Example:

```
public Etst() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    area.setLineWrap(true);
    f.add(area);
    f.setSize(100, 100);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that my program is GUI based so the user will be typing directly into the area, not appending it. I am unsure how to apply what you are telling me.

Comment: initialize the textarea -> call the command. i have the code from my gui where the users does type into it as well so its definitly working

Comment: Could you provide a little example?

Comment: added an example

Comment: @TreyCollier you should note that it does not insert a `\n` at the break. its just a visual break. if you take the text its a complete string